# javascript function not defined error on click on a button

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Imagine below MVC parent model:

**Model:**

```
Namespace MyProject.SampleModel
{
     public class ViewModelExample {
           public FirstModel BoolValues { get; set; }
           public SecondModel NamesValues { get; set; }
     }
}

Namespace MyProject.SampleModel
{
   public class FirstModel
   {
     public bool MyBoolean1 { get; set; }
     public bool MyBoolean2 { get; set; }
   }

   public class SecondModel
   {
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
   }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model MyProject.SampleModel.ViewModelExample

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { id = "Myform" }))
{

   (...)

   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.BoolValues.MyBoolean1)

   (...)

    <input id="submitButton" type="button" value="Add" onclick="InitiateSequence();" />

   (...)
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

      (...)

      function InitiateSequence()
      {
            // Do some stuff
      }

      (...)
      function ScriptSample() {

            if(@(Model.BoolValues.MyBoolean1 ? "true" : "false")
            {
                 // It's true, do some stuff
            }
            else
            {
                 // It's false, do some stuff
            }
      }

</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult MyAction(ViewModelExample model)
        {
            model.FirstModel = new TestsModel(); // I do not instantiate SecondModel as in the view for this controller i do not use it

            return View(model);
        }
```

Page is loading correctly, but when I click on the button it says javascript function InitiateSequence is not defined.... what's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That could be because most possibly the function appears where it is not supposed to be. Also don't use inline attributes to bind the handlers, use event binding instead of inline handler.

```
<input id="submitButton" type="button" value="Add" />
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  (...) //whatever code

  $(function(){
     $('#submitButton').on('click', InitiateSequence);
  });
```

Comment: I have modified my code and now using your solution when I click the button, nothing happens, function it is not called.

Comment: ok, now it works, i have seen in the console an error related to a missing parentheses. Now your solution works, many thanks!

Comment: I will do. I am newbie in web application development, only some weeks doing it... ;)

Comment: One thing more: do you know if there is a method to debug, establish breakpoints in javascript code?or only the console is the only way?

Comment: I use chrome console and place a line `debugger;` in javascript. and when you open it up in chrome console press f12 it will launch with all debug tools for you and will break in your debug statement for you to debug.